# Conflicting answers about Transiting Zurich International Airport

Tags: transit, zurich, tunisian-citizens

I am living & residing legally in the UAE for 10 years.
For return trip Dubai - Zurich - Djerba, Tunisia with a transit of 10 hours in inbound and outbound flights, here is what may happen:
VERSION 1: Swiss embassy "to know whether you are allowed to stay in the transit area consult the link". I did so I learned that I am a passport holder of a country that is exempted from a compulsory transit visa. Great I meet all the requirements.
VERSION 2 : Consulting Swiss airline check-in officers in Dubai Airport they said "After contacting police authorities in Zurich, we are assured that you and your family don't have the right to land on the airport". Transiting not allowed.
VERSION 3 : I mailed the passengers and immigration authorities at Zurich Airport and the answer was that I have the right to  transit the airport as I meet all the requirements.

Comment: No one can comment on your ability to transit in Zurich unless you reveal what country's passport you carry.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket? Do you have checked luggage?

Answer (score 3):

According to Timatic, transiting without a visa is possible for Tunisian citizens as follows:

Passengers transiting through Zurich (ZRH) and arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:

- stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
- have documents required for their next destination.

Changes of onward reservations at the transit station (i.e. once the passenger has arrived in Switzerland) are not allowed.

https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

Comment: Perfectly correct...assuming the OP is a Tunisian citizen.

Comment: @David Agree - I’m assuming the OP tagged his question correctly :-)

Comment: At the point I commented...I didn't see a "Tunisian citizens" tag. Maybe I missed it, maybe it was added since.